# Eloquent collection returned json

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How is that possible ? Le's say that in a controller we have something like :

```
 $something = Something:all();
```

If I just return $something, an json object is returned with content of table `{id:1, title :'etc'}`

However if I die dump `dd($something)`, I can see `$something` is an entire collection.

So the return is not returning the collection, is returning json object...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the magic of `Laravel`, when you return the collection it convert it to `json`automatically, this is an advantage for building an `api`.

> Note that when a model or collection is cast to a string, it will be
>   converted to JSON, meaning you can return Eloquent objects directly
>   from your application's routes!

Check [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) (`Converting A Model To JSON`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in addition to @Sheikh Heera answer, such conversion happens in the `Illuminate\Http\Resonse` class [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L35), by checking if the response content [is "JSONable"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L70), [which is true](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L13) for `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` inherits from.